# Android Studio warnings about gradle build files

Tags: utf-8

how can I solve such problem ..Warning:The project encoding (windows-1252) does not match the encoding specified in the Gradle build files (UTF-8). This can lead to serious bugs. [More Info...](http://tools.android.com/knownissues/encoding)
Open File Encoding Settings

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be in the link that you posted.

"When you encounter the above problem (which points to the this page), **either change your IDE setting** **s** or** build.gradle to UTF-8 such that the two matches**, or **(if necessary) change your encoding to whatever custom encoding you have specified such that the two are in agreement.**

(Note: If your source files contain more than plain ASCII characters, you can't "just" change the encoding to UTF-8. If your source files were written with a custom encoding, you'll need to convert them such that the actual characters are read in with the previous encoding and written out with the new encoding.)"